# Smarty Templates on live server

Tags: php, smarty

I am using smarty template with codeigniter. It is working perfectly fine on local server but it is not working on live server

The page is getting displayed as..
[image]

Please suggest me what's the problem. I am really very thankful for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but... what do you mean for "live server"?

You can find the problem in your "error.log" file and check if php and smarty is correctly configured on your "live server"

Comment: Iive server means not on localhost, It is working perfectly fine on localhost. 
Where should i look for the error.log. I'm integrating smarty first time with codigniter.

Comment: by default for apache on linux, the patch is "/var/log/apache2/error.log", if you have other installation type, xampp lamp wamp mamp uwamp... etc. can you tell me